# Python regular expression returning extra capture group for last character matched

Tags: python, regex, string, capture-group

I am trying to create a regular expression that will take strings and break them up into three groups: (1) Any one of a specific list of words at the beginning of a string. (2) Any one of  specific list of words at the end of a string. (3) all of the letters/whitespace in between these two matches.

As an example, I will use the following two strings:

```
'There was a cat in the house yesterday'
'Did you see a cat in the house today'
```

I would like the string to be broken up into capture groups so that the match object `m.groups()` will return the following for each string respectively:

```
('There', ' was a cat in the house ', 'yesterday')
('Did', ' you see a cat in the house ', 'today')
```

Originally, I came up with the following regex:

```
r = re.compile('^(There|Did) ( |[A-Za-z])+ (today|yesterday)$')
```

However this returns:

```
('There', 'e', 'yesterday')
('Did', 'e', 'today')
```

So it's only giving me the last character matched in the middle group. I learned that this doesn't work because capture groups will only return the last iteration that matched. So I put parentheses around the middle capture group as follows:

```
r = re.compile('^(There|Did) (( |[A-Za-z])+) (today|yesterday)$')
```

But now, although it does at least capture the middle group, it is also returning an extra "e" character in `m.groups()`, i.e.:

```
('There', 'was a cat in the house', 'e', 'yesterday')
```

... although I feel like this has something to do with backtracking, I can't figure out why it is happening. Could someone please explain to me why I am getting this result, and how I can get the desired results?

Comment: `^(There|Did) ([ A-Za-z]+) (today|yesterday)$`

Comment: Thank you for actually including a couple of attempted solutions in your question. There are far too many regex questions that don't show any work, and this isn't one of them. So thank you for that.

Comment: No problem - I think it's always useful for other folks who might be having a similar problem to see what *doesn't* work (and why) as well as knowing how to do it properly. Anyways, thanks for your answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 r = re.compile('^(There|Did) (( |[A-Za-z])+) (today|yesterday)$')
                               ^ ^        ^
```

you have some unnecessary stuff. Take those out and include spaces in your middle group:

```
r = re.compile('^(There|Did) ([A-Za-z ]+) (today|yesterday)$')
                                     ^ space
```

EXAMPLE:

```
>>> r = re.compile('^(There|Did) ([A-Za-z ]+) (today|yesterday)$')
>>> r.search('There was a a cat in the hosue yesterday').groups()
('There', 'was a a cat in the hosue', 'yesterday')
```

Also, take out the spaces in between your capture group if you want the spaces to be a part of your middle (2nd) group

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your current regex, and get the correct behavior, by replacing your middle capture group with the `.` (dot) operator that will match any character, followed by the `*` (asterisk) operator to repeatedly match any character:

```
import re

s1 = 'There was a cat in the house yesterday'
s2 = 'Did you see a cat in the house today'

x = re.compile("(There|Did)(.*)(today|yesterday)")
g1 = x.search(s1).groups()
g2 = x.search(s2).groups()

print(g1)
print(g2)
```

Produces this output:

> ('There', ' was a cat in the house ', 'yesterday')
>   ('Did', ' you see a cat in the house ', 'today')

Answer (score 1):

> A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a
>   capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or
>   use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the
>   data.

source https://regex101.com/

And here is the re working as expected:

```
^(There|Did) ([ A-Za-z]+) (today|yesterday)$
```